# Keycloack with NewRelic Transactions does not shows the route path

Tags: keycloak, newrelic

I am trying to monitor keycloak application., but it's only shows without routes

[image]

I am using the latest Newrelic agent with the Keycloac `20.0.3`

I tried to use

https://github.com/newrelic-experimental/newrelic-java-quarkus

but I got the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Probably in your `newrelic.yml` config file  there is an option  `enable_auto_transaction_naming` try to enable it